Creating an Accessible TypeScript Prototype for Next.js: Client-Side and Server-Side Implementation
I have a Next JS 14 App Router Project. I want to create a prototype function that is usable not only in the server side but also in the client side.
for example I have rwite this:
declare global {
  interface String {
    separateNumbers: () => String;
  }
}

String.prototype.separateNumbers = function () {
  return this.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

export {};


and then I import it like this: import "@utils/separateNumbers" in my root layout. But as it is expected my root layout is on the server side rendred but I use separateNumbers() in a client side rendered component and get this error.
My Implementation: card?.content?.value?.toString().separateNumbers()
The Error: TypeError: card.content.value.toString(...).separateNumbers is not a function
